# Different configurations for Unit and Integration Tests in PHPUnit

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

I would like to have different configuration files for PHPUnit for my

1. Unit Tests: no database available, no cache, no everything
2. integration tests: everything is there
   AND 
   to be able to execute these tests in PhpStorm all together or separated per file with automatically the right configuration.

There are several opportunities, which do not work for all needs:

**Option 1:** 
Multiple `phpunit.xml` files
In PhpStorm can only set one PHPUnit default configuration, for executing a single test file, this will not work.

**Option 2:** Using a `PHPUnit_Framework_BaseTestListener::startTestSuite($suite)`.
This works with a single `phpunit.xml` and if you are just executing the whole test suite, this works. But when you want to execute a single test file in PhpStorm, you do not have a `$suite` available and can not load the right configuration.

How do you handle different test configurations with PhpStorm?

Answer (score 1):

Because there seems to be no offical possiblity on PHPStorm, I figured out a way by using a PHPUnit TestListener:

https://sebastianviereck.de/run-phpunit-unit-integrations-test-configurations-phpstorm/

Comment: You should paste your solution here. If one day your blog disappears or moves to another url, this SO answer becomes useless.

Comment: If you take a look below to my full answer, you will it is possible to set unit tests and integrations tests in the same phpunit xml file

Answer (score -1):

PHPStorm can handle unit tests and integration tests in the same phpunit.xml file

1. Create two separate test suites in the same xml file. Each suite must have a distinct name in the name attribute.
2. Create two separate configurations for the tests
   in PHPStorm (one for the unit tests and one for the integration tests) and indicate the same xml configuration file path for both tests
3. In the "Test Runner options" field, indicate the test suite name (the same as the one in the xml file) like this: `--testsuite unit_tests`

```
<testsuites>

    <testsuite name="unit_tests">
        <directory>/foo</directory>
    </testsuite>

    <testsuite name="integration_tests">
        <directory>/bar</directory>
    </testsuite>

</testsuites>
```

[image]

Once you have done that you can run unit tests and integration tests separately and still have them configured in the same xml file

Comment: PhpStorm can only set one PHPUnit default configuration. So the same bootstrap will be used before tests initiated, regardless of the testsuite the test resides in.

Comment: That is why you must check the checkbox "use alternative configuration file"